# How to serve custom domains pointing to a subdomain in Saas App

Tags: dns, hosting, saas

I want to create an example SaaS app, whereby users are able to signup, create web pages, use templates and/or customize them with custom css, serve their web pages off custom domains.

I was considering saving the templates on S3/other CDNs, along with media/stylesheets/js files. While all are technically possible (practical? that could be debatable). Anyways, I was having a hard time figuring out how websites would be served off custom domains in this case? For instance, when they sign up, they could get a `subdomain.domain.com` address. However, how do they point `customerdomain.com` so that when `customerdomain.com` is entered, it serves same content as `customerdomain.domain.com`, and URL remains `customerdomain.com`

Additionally, if I want to have a "`feature`" whereby, custom domains could be a paid feature. How would I restrict it to paid users only?

Normally when, we setup websites, we specify it in virtual host config file (apache), and give it aliases, so it looks for and serves those aliases. In this case, I do not want to have a separate vhost file for each person who signs up. Is there an alternative? How can I program this? Are there any gotchas to be aware of?

One solution that I have seen is to have the server serve a wildcard domain i.e `*.domain.com`, and a separate vhost for each custom domain, however I would prefer to avoid if I can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The custom domain is usually done through a CNAME DNS record (sort of a symlink for DNS records). You tell your customer (who is usually in control of customerdomain.com) to create a CNAME record saying that customerdomain.com is an alias for customerdomain.domain.com. Then you need to set up your own server to interpret requests to customerdomain.com the same as it would treat requests to customerdomain.domain.com.

Depending on how you serve your subdomains, this can be done in a few different ways.

If you have a vhost file for every single customer, you need to add a "ServerAlias" directive for the custom domain your client has provided.

If you are coding the entry point through your own application server (say, reading the "Host" HTTP header from PHP and then setting the customer name from that) then you need to adjust that code accordingly to interpret requests for external domains according to your own database of custom domains. You can even use straight DNS for this!

Something on the lines of:

```
if http "host" header does not end in domain.com:
    cname = get_cname_record(http "host" header value)
    if cname does not end in domain.com:
        return error 404
    else:
        site = first part of cname
else:
    site = first part of http "host" header
```

Then you can use DNS as your "custom domain database". Make sure you are using a DNS cache though, as those queries will be performed on every single request.

Comment: thanks, your psuedocode helped in understanding the solution. About DNS cache, on a server is it not default? I mean DNS queries are cached by the OS (ubuntu). Do I need to do something extra for that?

Comment: That depends on how you implement "get_cname_record". If you use gethostbyaddr() or a derivative (the most likely option) your system typically provides some sort of caching already. But do benchmark it by looping a bunch of lookups so that you don't fall into a trap with this. I've seen it happen, so just an FYI.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good but it doesn't show the full picture.

If your customers just CNAME to your domain or create the A record to your IP and you don't handle TLS termination for these custom domains, your app will not support HTTPS, and without it, your app won't work in modern browsers on these custom domains.

You need to set up a TLS termination reverse proxy in front of your webserver. This proxy can be run on a separate machine but you can run it on the same machine as the webserver.

#### CNAME vs A record

If your customers want to have your app on their subdomain, e.g. `app.customer.com` they can create a CNAME `app.customer.com` pointing to your proxy.

If they want to have your app on their root domain, e.g. `customer.com` then they'll have to create an A record on `customer.com` pointing to your proxy's IP. Make sure this IP doesn't change, ever!

#### How to handle TLS termination?

To make TLS termination work, you'll have to issue TLS certificates for these custom domains. You can use Let's Encrypt for that. Your proxy will see the `Host` header of the incoming request, e.g. `app.customer1.com` or `customer2.com` etc., and then it will decide which TLS certificate to use by checking the SNI.

The proxy can be set up to automatically issue and renew certificates for these custom domains. On the first request from a new custom domain, the proxy will see it doesn't have the appropriate certificate. It will ask Let's Encrypt for a new certificate. Let's Encrypt will first issue a challenge to see if you manage the domain, and since the customer already created a CNAME or A record pointing to your proxy, that tells Let's Encrypt you indeed manage the domain, and it will let you issue a certificate for it.

To issue and renew certificates automatically, I'd recommend using Caddyserver, greenlock.js, OpenResty (Nginx).

tl;dr on what happens here;
Caddyserver listens on 443 and 80, it receives requests, issues, and renews certificates automatically, proxies traffic to your backend.

#### How to handle it on my backend

Your proxy is terminating TLS and proxying requests to your backend. However, your backend doesn't know who is the original customer behind the request. This is why you need to tell your proxy to include additional headers in proxied requests to identify the customer. Just add `X-Serve-For: app.customer.com` or `X-Serve-For: customer2.com` or whatever the `Host` header is of the original request.

Now when you receive the proxied request on the backend, you can read this custom header and you know who is the customer behind the request. You can implement your logic based on that, show data belonging to this customer, etc.

#### More

Put a load balancer in front of your fleet of proxies for higher availability. You'll also have to use distributed storage for certificates and Let's Encrypt challenges. Use AWS ECS or EBS for automated recovery if something fails, otherwise, you may be waking up in the middle of the night restarting machines, or your proxy manually.

Alternatively, there have been a few services like [this](https://saascustomdomains.com) recently that allow you to add custom domains to your app without running the infrastructure yourself.

If you need more detail you can DM me on Twitter [@dragocrnjac](https://twitter.com/dragocrnjac)